# What's the Best Way to Write Text to Blob in an Azure Webjob

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure Webjob. It's dequeuing a message and processing it. When it dequeues the message it uses the default model binder to enable me to have a strong-typed parameter. At the moment, the signature to that function looks like this:

```
DequeueCUWebinarMessages([QueueTrigger("tts-cuw-notifications-queue")] NotificationMessage notificationMessage, int dequeueCount, TextWriter log)
```

I want to store one of the properties of that NotificationMessage object to blob storage. The property in question is a string (specifically, html).

I am aware of the fact that there are Blob attributes which you can use in your WebJobs functions. So my question is, should I use one of those blob attributes? And if so, what would my new function signature look like?

Or, should I just use the storage client API to "upload" the string to a blob container?

What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WebJobs SDK to do that. Here is how the function could look like:

```
DequeueCUWebinarMessages(
    [QueueTrigger("tts-cuw-notifications-queue")] NotificationMessage notificationMessage, 
    [Blob("output/blob.txt")] out string blob,
    int dequeueCount, 
    TextWriter log)
{
     blob = "blob content";
}
```

Instead of `string` you can also use `Stream`, `TextWriter`, `CloudBlockBlob`, `ICloudBlob` or your own custom type if you implement a customer serializer.

Comment: Thanks, that did work. My next step is to name it dynamically. I think there was some kind of token you can use in the Blob attribute. I'll research that. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at our samples: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples . There are examples on how to have a dynamic name either based on some properties of the trigger or from a name resolver

Comment: Thanks Victor. That's been really helpful.